# How prevent change popper placement with scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, popper.js

I want to fix the popper element's position and not change the placement with later updates (without disabling the scroll listener).

The gif shows you my sticky popper, but I want it to be static. (don't change position on scroll):

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code ? I suppose you used `position: sticky;` ? Did you try `position: absolute;` ?

Comment: Yes! actually the provided gif is the default behavior of the popper, with scrolling the item, translate3d (`CSS property`) changes dynamically. @OneQ

Comment: There is little more we can do than guess what your issue is without a [reprex]. SO is not meant for dropping code developement assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popper uses some modifiers that are not customizable! Instead, I use a new library whose name is **Floating UI** (the evolution of Popper 2).

**Floating UI** extended modifiers to something new as middleware. One of them whose name is **shift** can be or not be in the middleware list to handle shifting popper elements in the exiting from viewport situation.

You can find further information at [Floating UI doc](https://floating-ui.com).

> shift() moves the floating element along the specified axes in order to keep it in view.